# Sort data column .NET C# and MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, sorting

I have a columns of data from SQL table in .net C# program where I need to resort data every x lines.

Example:

```
old data new data
1        3 
2        2 
3        1
1        3
2        2  
3        1
1        3
2        2
3        1
```

Is there some simple way to do this? I'd prefer SQL procedure solution since I could use it for report server too.

Comment: Only with one provided column this is quite difficult to answer. Do you want to achieve a "simple" reverted order or do you want to re-sort every three rows?

Comment: I want to re-sort every three rows in this example. Basically what I have in real case is just timestamp and measurement data I have to re-sort every n rows because it comes in reversed order. Think about if you put stuff in box and take it from box it comes in different order for every box.

Comment: Then you might want to try to change the `ROW_NUMBER` Part in my answer to the timestamp instead of `SELECT 1`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do so by using subqueries / ctes and WindowFunctions. Following a short example:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  ID int
  ,txt nvarchar(5)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 'a')
,(2, 'a')
,(3, 'a')
,(1, 'b')
,(2, 'b')
,(3, 'b')
,(1, 'c')
,(2, 'c')
,(3, 'c')


;WITH cte AS(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
    FROM @t
),
cte2 AS(
  SELECT *, (rn+2)/3 AS rn2
    FROM cte
)
SELECT ID, txt
  FROM cte2
  ORDER BY rn2, rn DESC
```

In this example I sort every three rows descending. However, sorting by `SELECT 1` is not good practice - it is strongly dependent on the order within your table. So, if you have any other column usable for a sort, you should use this...

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @t TABLE(
  ID int
  ,txt nvarchar(5)
)

DECLARE @stacksize AS int
SET @stacksize = 5
DECLARE @stackminusone AS int
SET @stackminusone = @stacksize - 1

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 'a')
,(2, 'a')
,(3, 'a')
,(4, 'b')
,(5, 'b')
,(6, 'b')
,(7, 'c')
,(8, 'c')
,(9, 'c')

;WITH cte AS(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
    FROM @t
),
cte2 AS(
  SELECT *, (rn+@stackminusone)/@stacksize AS rn2
    FROM cte
)
SELECT ID, txt
  FROM cte2
  ORDER BY rn2, rn DESC
```